# Let $M_{1}$, $M_{2} \subset{\mathbb{R}}$ and assume $M_{1}$ is open. Show $M_{1}+M_{2}$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Q: Let $M_{1}$, $M_{2} \subset{\mathbb{R}}$ and assume $M_{1}$ is open. Show $M_{1}+M_{2}$ is open.

Okay so I know I need to show $U_{h}(m_1 + m_2)\in{M_{1} + M_{2}}$.

I am new to neighborhoods and am having trouble on how to start, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

*Hint?*:

$$M_1+M_2=\bigcup_{x\in M_2}(x+M_1)$$

$M_1$ is a Bigfoot's footprint. $M_2$ is the set of points where Bigfoot's has stepped.

Comment: Why is $M_{1} + m$ where $m\in{M_{2}}$ open?

Comment: Let $y\in x+M_1$. Then $y-x\in M_1$. Since $M_1$ is open, there exists an open interval $I$ such that $y-x\in I\subset M_1$. Then $x+I$ is an open interval and $y\in x+I\subset x+M_1$.

Answer (score 2):

For each point $m\in M_2$, the set $M_1+\{m\}$ is just a translate of $M_1$. The set $M_1+M_2$ is the union of all of these. Arbitrary unions of open sets are open.

Does that work?

Comment: Why is $M_{1} + m$ where $m\in{M_{2}}$ open?

Comment: For any open set $U$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $U+a$ is open because the mapping $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x+a$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\in M_1+M_2.$ Then there exist $m_1\in M_1,\ m_2\in M_2 $ such that $x=m_1+m_2$. Since $M_1$ is open choose a nbhd $U$ of $m_1$ such that $U\subseteq M_1$. Put $V=U+\{m_2\} $. Then $V$ is a nbhd of $x$ and $V\subseteq M_1+M_2$. Hence $M_1+M_2$ is open.